# Variables with 0 Covariance that are NOT independent.

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, independence, covariance

I have a few examples I could provide, here is one. Let X = Uniform(-1,1) and X = $Y^2$. Here we have clearly E(X) = 0 and then E(Y) = $\frac{1}{3}$.

Cov(X,Y) = E(X*Y) - E(X) * E(Y) = E($X^3$) - 0 = E($X^3$) = 0. But obviously X and Y are not independent as Y is quite literally valued from X. What does this really mean? What is the interpretation of "Covariance" ? Any insight into some theory behind statistics would be greatly appreciated. :)

Oskar

Comment: Perhaps you meant $Y=X^2$

Comment: The simplest explanation is that covariance/correlation is only a measure of linear dependence. So, although $X^2$ does not have a linear dependence on $X$ it does have a quadratic dependence on $X$, and is therefore not independent of $X$.

Comment: Yes I do indeed mean Y = X^2 and thank you very much Leander!